# Integrity error in inserting a transaction odoo 8

Tags: python, docker, odoo

> Integrity Error
>
> The operation cannot be completed, probably due to the following:
>
> - deletion: you may be trying to delete a record while other records still reference it
> - creation/update: a mandatory field is not correctly set
>
> [object with reference: date - date]

The model is good_reception. It's a custom module.

The different transactions take the date of that good reception. Yesterday it was working perfectly then I deleted all the draft data and now it is displaying that error.

Note that I did a backup of the database but I can't restore it. The error is

```
<br><br>could not restore the database
<br><br><code>
supplier = fields.Many2one("res.partner", string="Supplier",required=True)
    received_goods = fields.One2many("rcs.stock_transaction", "reception")
    received_by  = fields.Many2one("res.users", readonly=True)
    date = fields.Date(required=False)
    state = fields.Selection([
     ('pending', "Pending"),
     ('received', "Received"),
    ], default='pending', readonly=True)


    @api.one
    def compute_name(self):
            self.name = "Reception No:"+str(self.id)+", Supplier:"+self.supplier.name+", Date:"+self.date
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about which model you are on, but it seems like you are creating record of some model and not providing value for the required field which is date in your case.

After providing the value you for the date field the error will get resolve.

If you are still having the issue please update your question with detailed information like model and full error traceback, which will be helpful for us.